# How can I return an array from an object key value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

So I have the following piece of code:

```
var structures = {

    loginStructure : function(){

        return structure = [
            '<form name="',opts.formClass,'" class="',opts.formClass,'" method="post" action="#">',
                '<fieldset class="',opts.fieldsWrapper,'">',
                    '<fieldset class="',opts.userWrapper,'">',
                        '<label for="',opts.userInt,'" class="',opts.userLbl,'"><img src="',opts.userIcon,'" alt="',opts.userName,'" /></label>',
                        '<input type="text" name="',opts.userInt,'" class="',opts.userInt,'" placeholder="',checkNameLenght(opts.userName,namesLenght.userNameLenght,16,'Username'),'" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
                    '</fieldset>',
                    '<fieldset class="',opts.passWrapper,'">',
                        '<label for="',opts.passInt,'" class="',opts.passLbl,'"><img src="',opts.passIcon,'" alt="',opts.passName,'" /></label>',
                        '<input type="password" name="',opts.passInt,'" class="',opts.passInt,'" placeholder="',checkNameLenght(opts.passName,namesLenght.passNameLenght,16,'Password'),'" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
                    '</fieldset>',
                    '<fieldset class="',opts.btnWrapper,'">',
                        '<button type="submit" name="',opts.btnInt,'" class="',opts.btnInt,'">',checkNameLenght(opts.btnName,namesLenght.btnNameLenght,7,'Login'),'</button>',
                    '</fieldset>',
                '</fieldset>',
                '<div class="toogle-button">',
                    '<ul class="inside">',
                        '<li class="toogle"><a><img src="assets/gfx/toogle.png" alt="Back" /></a></li>',
                    '</ul>',
                '</div>',
            '</form>',
            '<div class="toogle-buttons">',
            '</div>'
        ];
    }

}
```

This returns ( if I do `console.log(structures.loginStructure)` ) just a `function()`. Is there a way I can make it to return the actual array I have in there ?

The purpose of it would be to have multiple arrays defined as object keys, if it is possible to return such a thing, because it seems easier. Or is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: BTW, this has nothing to do with jQuery - but leaving it tagged as such as an indication that you're probably using jQuery - which may act as a hint to someone else to provide a jQuery-dependent answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm using jQuery too, in fact this piece of code is part of a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Seems to work fine here if all variables are defined properly: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ekZVE/.

Comment: @jfriend00 indeed it does. I have the following structure of the jQuery plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/3fbZq/1/ , and the opts are defined within that `$.fn.loginsys.defaults = { ... }` . And if I run that `console.log()` operation nothing shows up in this current state. If I had that object return a function as the first part of the answer says it shows as I described `function()` in the console. So maybe something is wrong with my structure of the plugin and that is why it's not working properly. If you don't mind you could take a look http://jsfiddle.net/3fbZq/1/ and tell me what's wrong.

Comment: @Roland - I made your fiddle so it will actually run and execute and when I do that, it gives errors saying that the `namesLenght` object is not defined and thus it aborts.  Also, do you realize that the normal spelling is `namesLength` not `namesLenght`.  You can see the runnable version and the error here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rdbfU/.

Comment: @jfriend00, sorry, I'm just using jsfiddle for the first time. Yes, I see, I now placed the `nameLenght` object above the `return this.each()` function and if I click JSLint there are only some semicolons error which I cannot see. So how do I see in the fiddle if the console outputs something ? That to see if that object actually returns something, because the object it's used for other things in the rest of the code in the plugin.

Comment: After you save a change in jsFiddle, in Chrome (which I use), you can right click on the lower right pane in jsFiddle and then click on the console tab to see whatever errors are present.

Comment: Oh, I'm using Firebug so I assumed that the response would be printed out in that console. Well, after moving the `nameLength` object up in the head of the code it worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
structures.loginStructure();
```

`structures.loginStructure` is simply just returning a reference to the function, instead of executing the function and returning its result.  Add the `()` to the end of it to execute it and return its result.

Alternatively, and maybe better, don't write it as a function.  Just declare `loginStructure: ['<form name...`.  Basically, just remove `function(){return structure =`.  A significant difference to note here is that any values of opts would be evaluated immediately, instead of deferred until later when then function would be executed - so please don't blindly update your code to this.

Comment: And instead of `',opts.formClass,'` having `'+opts.formClass+'` ?

Comment: I tried but then it gives me an error down on my code on which line I have `return this.each(function() { .......` , why ?

Comment: @Roland - I think we'd need to see more code to accurately answer that, which I think may be appropriate for a new question.

Comment: Sorry, my fault here, I forgot to delete `}` from the end of the `funtion(){ ...` I had there before. It's fine now, but now nothing happens if I do this `console.log(structures.loginStructure)`, I'm suppose to see that array, no ?

Comment: @Roland - eliminate the trailing `;` after the closing `]` as well - it's not valid syntax.  You're probably never even getting to the `console.log`.

Comment: It's gone, otherwise I would get an error. It just prints nothing in the console.

Comment: @Roland - this works for me:  http://pastebin.com/3qd32DLZ .  (Note that I had to mock-up some of the missing functions and objects at the top.)

Comment: Ok, so it has something to do with the options then ? Because indeed if I remove that it works, but with it it doesn't. What is there to be done then ? Can I actually do something ?

Comment: This answer no longer related to the current state of the question (after it was edited).

Comment: @Roland - jfriend00 is completely correct; I reverted your question to the previous edit to reflect this.  It sounds like you'd be better off with the first recommendation in my answer - just ensure that you're executing the function instead of using its reference.  And yes, you'll need to ensure that your `opts` and other variables are properly in-scope of this function.